# Excel Issue: Object Variable or with block Variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that works for me about 70% of the time, the other times it throws the **Error** code **91** **`"Object Variable or With block Variable not set"`**. If i click End and re-run it it will work fine.

The function is taking data that is entered into cells of an excel spreadsheet and populating text boxes, checking radio buttons, and selecting from drop-down lists on a webpage.

I can't post a link to the actual webpage for privacy issues but I'm hoping someone can help me why the error is coming up?

The line that shows the error is 
 **`drp.selectedIndex = Thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1").Range("L2").`**

```
Sub FillInternetForm()
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'set references for copying to submitted reps sheet and deleting for next                  rep
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'create new instance of IE.

ie.navigate "removed for privacy"

'go to web page listed inside quotes
ie.Visible = True


While ie.busy
DoEvents 'wait until IE is done loading page.
Wend

'select onboarding system CRIS or ENS
Set html = ie.document
Dim drp As HTMLFormElement
Set drp =     html.getElementById("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff45_1$ctl00    $DropDownChoice")
drp.selectedIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("L2")

'set address nickname based on value
Set drp =     html.getElementById("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff32_1$ctl00    $Lookup")
drp.selectedIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("m2")

'set market based on value
Set drp =     html.getElementById("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff6_1$ctl00$    DropDownChoice")
drp.selectedIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("e2")

'check Not moved from another partner
ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e_ff46_1_ctl00_ctl01").Click

'input name and ssn based on excel sheet values
ie.document.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff3_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a2")
ie.document.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff4_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("b2")
ie.document.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff5_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("c2")

'input extra fields based on ICL value
'owner
ie.document.all("ctl00_m_g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e_ff11_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("j2")
'city
ie.document.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff14_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("f2")
'state
ie.document.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff15_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("g2")
'address
ie.document.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff13_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("i2")
'phone
    ie.document.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff10_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("k2")
'zip
ie.document.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff16_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("h2")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`While ie.busy` is probably to blame.  Use `Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE` instead.

I would cast `.Range("L2")` as an integer using `CInt(.Range("L2"))`.  You have a reference to the HTML Object library set.  You should go ahead and add a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls.  This way you'll get advantages of intellisense and internet constants.  If you don't want to set the reference add `Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4` to the code and change the ie references back

```
Sub FillInternetForm()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    'set references for copying to submitted reps sheet and deleting for next rep
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'create new instance of IE.

    ie.navigate "removed for privacy"

    'go to web page listed inside quotes
    ie.Visible = True

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    With Sheets("sheet1")

        'select onboarding system CRIS or ENS
        Set doc = ie.document
        Dim drp As HTMLFormElement
        Set drp = HTML.getElementById("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff45_1$ctl00    $DropDownChoice")
        drp.selectedIndex = CInt(.Range("L2"))

        'set address nickname based on value
        Set drp = HTML.getElementById("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff32_1$ctl00    $Lookup")
        drp.selectedIndex = CInt(.Range("m2"))

        'set market based on value
        Set drp = HTML.getElementById("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff6_1$ctl00$    DropDownChoice")
        drp.selectedIndex = CInt(.Range("e2"))

        'check Not moved from another partner
        doc.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e_ff46_1_ctl00_ctl01").Click

        'input name and ssn based on excel sheet values
        doc.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff3_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").value = .Range("a2")
        doc.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff4_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").value = .Range("b2")
        doc.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff5_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").value = .Range("c2")

        'input extra fields based on ICL value
        'owner
        doc.all("ctl00_m_g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e_ff11_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").value = .Range("j2")
        'city
        doc.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff14_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").value = .Range("f2")
        'state
        doc.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff15_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").value = .Range("g2")
        'address
        doc.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff13_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").value = .Range("i2")
        'phone
        doc.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff10_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").value = .Range("k2")
        'zip
        doc.all("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff16_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField").value = .Range("h2")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thomas, thank you for your input. I tried utilizing the code with the corrections you made but when I use the above code it get the Error 424 Object Required Error on the Set drp lines. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Thomas Inzina in that it's probably because the document hasn't fully loaded yet.

But I've found with my past projects that the best way to handle these 30% failure rates is to just "wait a bit longer" before processing or referring to elements.

Try adding a DoEvents and a Sleep command before you selectedIndex call.
See if it makes a difference

At the top of your module (before any subs are declared)

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Then add the two lines before you start set the doc variable

```
Doevents
Sleep 2000 ' Sleep two seconds (2000 ms)
Set doc = ie.document
```

You can play with the sleep value once you get a number that works for you

> **EDIT - added solution**

A more reliable way is to actually run a loop that has DoEvents/Sleep and an incrementing counter for numTries. It exits the loop only when the check for getElementById doesn't fail - or your maxTries counter is reached.

Pretty simple loop but let me know if you need an example

> **EDIT - EXAMPLE:** A wait until loaded loop

**Change this**

```
Set drp = HTML.getElementById("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff45_1$ctl00    $DropDownChoice")
drp.selectedIndex = CInt(.Range("L2"))
```

**To this:**

```
Dim iTries As Integer
Dim iMaxTries As Integer ' it's better to turn this into a const at top of your sub

iMaxTries = 3
iTries = 0
While (iTries < iMaxTries) And IsNull(HTML.getElementById("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff45_1$ctl00    $DropDownChoice"))
    iTries = iTries + 1
    DoEvents
    Sleep 750 ' try 3/4 second delays to start with
Wend

If iTries = iMaxTries Then
    MsgBox "Did not load HTML element in " & iMaxTries & " tries"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Should all be loaded and ready to process now
Set drp = HTML.getElementById("ctl00$m$g_62853594_bb4b_4cec_8b5c_17fb6abb735e$ff45_1$ctl00    $DropDownChoice")
drp.selectedIndex = CInt(.Range("L2"))
```

Comment: I will implement this an update you on my results. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds good - I added additional idea for you to try - it will prove what's happening if you add a Debug.Print in the loop to check for the ID

Comment: I'm new to VBA and learning this as I go so an example would be awesome! Thanks for your help